# How do I trigger a jquery function after inserting html content dynamically through an AJAX request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
                 <div id="timeline">

                   <ul class="grow" id="grown"><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li><li>Six</li><li>Seven</li><li>Eight</li><li>Nine</li><li>Ten</li><li>Eleven</li><li>Twelve</li><li>Thirteen</li><li>Fourteen</li><li>Fifteen</li><li>Sixteen</li><li>Seventeen</li><li>Eighteen</li><li>Nineteen</li><li>Twenty</li><li>Twentyone</li><li>Twentytwo</li><li>Twentythree</li><li>Twentyfour</li><li>Twentyfive</li><li>Twentysix</li><li>Twentyseven</li><li>Twentyeight</li><li>Twentynine</li><li>Thirty</li><li>Thirtyone</li><li>Thirtytwo</li><li>Thirtythree</li><li>Thirtyfour</li><li>Thirtyfive</li><li>Thirtysix</li><li>Thirtyseven</li><li>Thirtyeight</li><li>Thirtynine</li><li>Forty</li><li>Fortyone</li><li>Fortytwo</li><li>Fortythree</li><li>Fortyfour</li><li>Fortyfive</li><li>Fortysix</li><li>Fortyseven</li><li>Fortyeight</li><li>Fortynine</li><li>Fifty</li><li>Fiftyone</li><li>Fiftytwo</li><li>Fiftythree</li><li>Fiftyfour</li><li>Fiftyfive</li><li>Fiftysix</li><li>Fiftyseven</li><li>Fiftyeight</li><li>Fiftynine</li><li>Sixty</li><li>Sixtyone</li><li>Sixtytwo</li><li>Sixtythree</li><li>Sixtyfour</li><li>Sixtyfive</li><li>Sixtysix</li><li>Sixtyseven</li><li>Sixtyeight</li><li>Sixtynine</li><li>Seventy</li><li>Seventyone</li><li>Seventytwo</li><li>Seventythree</li><li>Seventyfour</li><li>Seventyfive</li><li>Seventysix</li><li>Seventyseven</li><li>Seventyeight</li><li>Seventynine</li><li>Eighty</li><li>Eightyone</li><li>Eightytwo</li><li>Eightythree</li><li>Eightyfour</li><li>Eightyfive</li><li>Eightysix</li><li>Eightyseven</li><li>Eightyeight</li><li>Eightynine</li><li>Ninety</li><li>Ninetyone</li><li>Ninetytwo</li><li>Ninetythree</li><li>Ninetyfour</li><li>Ninetyfive</li><li>Ninetysix</li><li>Ninetyseven</li><li>Ninetyeight</li><li>Ninetynine</li></ul>

                     </div>
                    <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert("hi");
        stroll.bind('.grow');

});

    </script>
```

This code works when load this html on a browser. BUt whenever I make an AJAX request to a server side php

timeline.php code

```
<?php
$pg = pg_connect("host=localhost user=postgres password=vinit dbname=postgres");
//or die("Can't connect to database.");
if (!$pg)
{ 
echo "Couldn't make a connection!"; 
}
$page=$_GET['page'];
$sql1="select year,year_description,page_link from timeline48 where year<2020 order by year asc ";
echo "<ul class='grow' id='grow'>";
while ($row1 = pg_fetch_array($result1, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $year =$row1['year'];
    $desc=$row1['year_description'];
    $link=$row1['page_link'];

    echo "<li>".$year."    ";
    echo "".$desc."  <a href='".$link."' target='_blank'>more..</a></li>";
    $count++;
}
echo "<ul>";
   echo "</nav>";

?>
```

After adding the list content dynamically, `stroll.bind('.grow')` doesn't work!
( I want to use `stroll.bind` to work for adding scroll effect to a list )

Comment: I'm not real good with this area of JavaScript so I'm sure someone else can help you out more but you need to delegate the events using `.on` or `.live` (if using jQuery 1.6 or below). The event is being bound to the content on screen. `.on` however binds to dynamically added content as well.

Comment: However, `.on` requires an event, and there is no event in this case.

Comment: You're missing an opening `<nav>` element in your php-html btw.

Comment: @Kevin B  ....could u give me an example of .on or .live

Comment: In what context? it won't work in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Add stroll.bind to the success of your ajax request.

```
$.ajax(...).done(function(){
    stroll.bind(".grow");
});
```

or

```
$.post(...).done(function(){
    stroll.bind(".grow");
});
```

or

```
$.get(...).done(function(){
    stroll.bind(".grow");
});
```

or

```
$.getJSON(...).done(function(){
    stroll.bind(".grow");
});
```

or

```
$(element).load("file.php",function(){
    stroll.bind(".grow");
});
```

or (from comments)

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("timeline").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        stroll.bind(".grow");
    } 
}
```

Comment: if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("timeline").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  
xmlhttp.open("GET","timeline.php?page="+page,true);
xmlhttp.send();

Comment: This is the way I make my ajax requests

Comment: Bingo ...Sorry I am new to all this!